# JQuery PrettyPhoto issue on iPad

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

Im using PrettyPhoto plugin in my website which works well on all major browsers. The issue is when I see it on iPad, it does not overlaying the complete screen and also image box is not showing in center of screen. Following is a demo site for the plugin:

http://www.davidjuth.com/jquery-slideshow-prettyPhoto.aspx

and you can use the following iPad simulator to see the issue:

http://ipadpeek.com/

Try to open the demo site in above simulator, when page load, scroll to the right and then see the overlay size and image box position.

Any help in this regards will be appreciated.